# Transition back from keyframe mid-animation

Tags: css, css-transitions

I am looking for a way to transition back from a `rotate` transition mid-keyframe. I have a long-running keyframe which repeatedly transforms from `0deg` to `360deg`.

When that animation is stopped (via class removal), I want the element to go back to `0deg`, **from the current position**. Currently, I am using a second keyframe to animate back to `0deg`, but that one always spins the full `360deg` back to `0deg`, which is not what I want.

I made a JSFiddle to demonstrate the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/egdct6qz/2/

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that using the following combination of CSS and JavaScript, which uses `getComputedStyle ()`.

```js
const circle = document.querySelector (".circle");

circle.onclick = () => {
    if (circle.classList.contains ("circle--spinning")) {
     // Get rotation and start animating back
        let currentRotation = getRotationDegrees (circle);
        animateRotationBack (currentRotation);
    }
    
    // Toggle the spinning itself
    circle.classList.toggle ("circle--spinning");
} 

function animateRotationBack (angle) {
 const keyframe = `
     @keyframes spin-back {
         from { transform: rotate(${angle}deg); }
            to { transform: rotate(0deg); }
        }
    `;

    // Get inserted style-tag or create a new one
    const style = document.getElementById ("spin-back-kf") || document.createElement ("style");
    style.textContent = keyframe;
    style.id = "spin-back-kf";
    
    // Remove previously inserted style tag if existant
    style.parentNode && style.parentNode.removeChild (style);
    
    // Append style tag and set animation
    document.body.appendChild (style);
}

function getRotationDegrees (element) {
    // get the computed style object for the element
    const style = window.getComputedStyle (element);
     
    // this string will be in the form 'matrix(a, b, c, d, tx, ty)'
    let transformString = style["-webkit-transform"]
                       || style["-moz-transform"]
                       || style["transform"];
                       
    if (!transformString || transformString === "none")
        return 0;
        
    // Remove matrix notation
    transformString = transformString
     .substr (0, transformString.length - 2)
        .substr (7);
    
    // Split and parse to floats
    const parts = transformString
     .split (",")
        .map (num => parseFloat (num));
        
    // Destructure in a and b
    let [a, b] = parts;
    
    // Doing atan2 on (b, a) will give you the angle in radians
    // Convert it to degrees and normalize it from (-180...180) to (0...360)
    const degrees = ((180 * Math.atan2 (b, a) / Math.PI) + 360) % 360;
    
    return degrees;
}
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
    margin: 5% auto;
    text-align: center;
}

.circle {
    padding: 3em;
    border-radius: 3em;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #EE5622;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    
    animation: .5s spin-back forwards;
}

.circle--spinning {
    animation: 2s spin infinite linear;
}

.square {
    padding: 1em;
    background-color: #F1F7ED;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    display: inline-block;
}

@keyframes spin {
    from {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <span class="circle circle--spinning">
        <span class="square"></span>
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: This seems overly complex to achieve the result we get there. It's what I need, but it really doesn't shine bright in terms of code quality, considering that we need JS to control our CSS animation. Is there really no pure CSS way to achieve this effect?

Comment: i don't think you can get the current rotation of the element with just pure css - that's why my solution gets the rotation from  `getComputedStyle()` and then generate the @keyframes with that value - i agree it's quite an overkill for such a 'simple' task

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I hope there will be a way to do stuff like this in the future.